# Google Analytics Gtag Option not Reporting Pageviews

Tags: google-analytics

I have a one page website that I have been developing on. I put the Gtag code just in the head section of the html page like they said to do. When I put the code in and tested it with google analytics it appeared to be working, however it only shows realtime viewers. It hasn't been tracking pageviews. All it ever shows is one page view no matter how many people look at it. Can someone help me with this?

This is the code I have in the head section of my html.

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-150005811-1"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-150005811-1');
    });
</script>
```

I also am not sure if it affects anything but there is some Javascript utilizing a script called [backstretch](https://www.jquery-backstretch.com/) running to change the background image every few seconds.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="backstretch.js"></script>
<script>
    $.backstretch([
        "images/spreader1.jpg",
        "images/feedlot3.jpg",
        "images/spreader2.jpg",
        "images/field1.jpg"
    ], {
    fade: 1000,
    duration: 7000
    });
</script>
```

Here are some images from the Google Tag Assistant report.
[Tag Assistant Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3ypa.png)
[Google Analytics Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUBsq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your header code you missed the closing <\script> tag after the second script. Add this and then review the data

Comment: It's a one page Site currently.

Comment: Yes I can unfortunetly it stopped working agan and nothing works...

Comment: There are some times delays which may be what you are seeing. Download a chrome Extension called tag assistant and view your site, this will tell you if the hits are being sent, If they are then you just need to wait

Comment: Before the realtime view was working very well but now it refuses to work. I added some images of the reports... Just tell me if you need any more. I looked at the results myself and it looks kinda like its sending the hits or it at least looks like it is. on the google analytics side it looks like its not really getting them...

Comment: You have missed the second script tag in your gtag code

Comment: I don't see what you mean but its working now! I fixed a javascript error and its working! Thanks for all your effort!